# Are breadcrumbs derived from the menu?

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

It is my understanding that in Drupal 7, breadcrumbs are primarily (core) formed from the menu. Thus what happens with nodes (pages) which are not menu related? Are the breadcrumb derived from the title node?